# in_array not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

So i have a very simple snippet. I studied the `in_array` command and found it would be what i need.

However its not working?

I have tried several scenarios:

`$this->item->tour_days` is an array containing 1,2,3

test 1

```
    $days = $this->item->tour_days;

    $array = array($days);

    if (in_array(2,$array,TRUE)) {

    echo 'Tuesday';

    }
```

test 2

```
    $days = $this->item->tour_days;

    $array = array($days);

    if (in_array(2,$array)) {

    echo 'Tuesday';

    }
```

test 3

```
    $days = $this->item->tour_days;

    $array = array($days);

    if (in_array('2',$array)) {

    echo 'Tuesday';

    }
```

I have tried to echo Tuesday where Tuesday = 2 from my csv but no luck.

Thanks in advance for nay help here
jonny

Comment: if i echo $days i get 1,2,3. So why? is this weird or am i completely brain dead?

Comment: `$days` is a string, not an array. Use `explode()` to get an array of the values.

Comment: what do you get if you run `print_r($this->item->tour_days);`?

Comment: if $days is an array containing 1, 2, 3... why are you doing this: `$array = array($days);`

Comment: @ialarmedalien who downvoted my question? why? is there something i did wrong?

Comment: @jonnypixel no idea. People downvote for lots of different reasons, or for no reason at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a string containing a comma-delimited list into an array, use `explode`:

```
$array = explode(',', $days);
```

Comment: @AresDraguna Check his comment, he says that `echo $days` prints `1,2,3`. Since `echo` doesn't work for arrays, it must be a string.

Comment: I know but then he says: `$this->item->tour_days` is an array containing 1,2,3

Comment: I know what he said, but he's wrong. He clearly doesn't know the difference between arrays and strings.

Comment: @AresDraguna I would guess that he just *thinks* it is an array because it's several numbers in a row, separated by commas.

Comment: I'm not saying that he is... I'm saying that you cannot be sure of your answer until we clarify this with the user

Comment: @Barmar wrong is my middle name LOL. SHiver Mi Timbers what you said makes total sense dude. Thanks for teaching me another thing.

Comment: @AresDraguna The user did clarify. Read his first comment where he said he did `echo $days`. This would echo `Array` if it were an array instead of a string.

Comment: @Barmar I know that... But he doesn't... All I'm saying is that, from my experience (which is not vast, I'll give you that  :)) ) you cannot say for sure anything when it comes to newbies... They are like babies... You know... Like that movie whit Denzel, Philadelphia: *"Tell it to me like I'm a 5 year old!"* :)

Comment: @jonnypixel so just var_dump $days like this: `var_dump($days);` if the first word is `string` then it's a string if it's `array` then it's an array

Comment: @AresDraguna slow down now man. I might be a nubie but i aint no baby. Covered in tatts and 41yrs of age mate living in the land of oz. So slow up there buddy pal as they say here in the land down under. Baramar answer was right so lets get over it and go eat some roo! Baramar - im now playing bridge!

Comment: @AresDraguna But he doesn't do what? He posted a comment that makes it very clear what the variable is. I've also been doing this kind of thing on Usenet for over 25 years, I've gotten very good at deciphering what newbies mean.

Comment: @jonnypixel :)) no baby! got it! sorry :)

Comment: oh dear what have i done! opened up a can of worms for one little snippet. I have basically learned that you can not place a value containing a csv unless you explode it into a csv because its not really a csv that the in_array command can understand ;) there's my nuby / baby view of this. Im just enjoying this - im no super geek and trust me there's always someone better / smarter in this world.

Comment: Please don't make a discussion in the comments! jonnnypixel should accept this answer how helpt him and if he has still the problem then he should say what's not working.

Comment: I did accept it, i had to wait 9 minutes ;) i was just trying to be nice in a nice kind of way. Thanks for your hep everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = explode(",",$days);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->item->tour_days` is an array containing 1,2,3

Then why do you want to make another array out of it?

remove the `$array = array($days);` converstion.

Instead say `$array = $days;`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

If `$days` is a string then use this:

```
    $days = "1,2,3";  //$this->item->tour_days;

    $array = explode(',', $days);

    if(in_array(2, $array))
        echo "Tuesday";


?>
```

If `$days` is already an array use this:

```
<?php

    $days = array(1,2,3);  //$this->item->tour_days;

    if(in_array(2, $days))
        echo "Tuesday";


?>
```